# How precise does the time synchronization of a PD cluster need to be? What happens if the time in the PD servers is not consistent?

Tags: tidb, tidb-pd

I'm struggling with the time synchronization of the PD servers, can't figure out a good way to guarantee the precision of it. Does anyone know the answers to the above two questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's recommended to use NTP to guarantee the time synchronization of PD servers, because the current time synchronization precision that NTP achieves can satisfy the time synchronization requirement of PD servers.
2. Inconsistent time in the PD servers might produce a smaller TSO after switching the leader, and thus applying for TSO is temporarily out of service. On the application level, it returns an error code.
3. Theoretically, the smaller of the tolerance for time synchronization error of PD, the better. During leader changes, if the clock goes back, the process won't proceed until it catches up with the previous leader. PD can tolerate any synchronization error, but a larger error value means a longer period of service stop during the leader change.